# Preventing an Openlayers WMS layer from updating on zoom-change

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, javascript, wms, mapserver

I'm using openlayers to overlay a raster. When I zoom out, the overlaid layer expands to cover a larger area than was originally requested. I want the tile to be fixed to a particular boundary, and for the WMS query to end, once the zoom changes. When I get the WMS layer the first time, it looks like this:

[image]

However, if I zoom out the screen then looks like this:

[image]

My javascript is as follows:

```
wms_url = 'mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=population.map&ny_pop';

oldRaster = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
               "pop_raster",
               wms_url, 
               {    layers: wms_layer, 
                    transparent: true
                    },
               {    maxExtent: polyBounds, 
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
                    tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(tileWidth, tileHeight),                   
                    opacity: 0.3, 
                    gutter: 0
                    }   
           );
           map.addLayer(oldRaster);
```

I've tried adding the attribute `persist: false` but it does not change anything. I calculate `polyBounds` using the screen size, and then `tileHeight` and `tileWidth` based on the screen resolution so that one tile fills the box that is drawn on-screen.

When I inspect the `GET` command using `HTTPFox` the page seems to be actively pulling down more data from the WMS, but I'm not sure why as there are no fresh requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending this to wms_url : `&BBOX=-97.105,24.913,78.794,36.358` but replace the values in this order: minimum longitude, minimum latitude, maximum longitude, maximum latitude.

Make sure the Bounding Box area overlaps with the BoundingBox advertised in the Capabilities XML for the requested geodata object.

Your not using a BBox Strategy anywhere else in your code? This would cause it to make new calls to the server.

Comment: hmm. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but am now just getting a blank tile. My `wms_url` is: `http://site.com/mapserv.cgi?map=population.map&  new_york_pop&BBOX=-8239644,4974211,-8230593,4979952&` I tried both with and without the `&` at the end.

Comment: Thanks can you give me the values for `polyBounds` and `wms_layer` so i can test?

Comment: Thanks CaptDragon - here they are: Polybounds  (left, right, bottom, top): `-8239644 -8230593 4974211 4979952`, wms_url:
`http://urbmet.webfactional.com/mapserv.cgi?map=population.map&`, 
wms_layer: `new_york_pop`

Comment: Strange thing is if you make the tiles really small like: `tileSize:new OpenLayers.Size(10,10),` then it will work but it takes for ever to load. If you increase the size it increases the size of the bounds error margin.

Comment: hmmm. I was wondering whether it could also be explained by openlayers using `GET` instead of `POST`. Not sure I know enough to change how openlayers is handling all of this but it seems like there might be some way of killing the command from remaining alive.

Comment: It's almost like the maxExtent is only restricting the left and bottom, but not the top and right. [this request works](http://urbmet.webfactional.com/mapserv.cgi?map=population.map&new_york_pop&LAYERS=new_york_pop&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&BUFFER=0&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-74.102096557618,40.6494140625,-73.89129638672,40.74966430664&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256) fine so it's something with the OpenLayers config/code.

Comment: if you are ready to change some code you can update OL script. i can tell you where if you need